# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray when the return is array

Tags: android, arrays, json

it is showing me the following error:

JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Here is my code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetTabDataResult");
```

My JSON Result:

```
{"GetTabDataResult":{"TabId":1,"Bands":[{"Id":1,"ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/bands\/1.jpg","BrandId":0,"Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":true,"Disabled":false,"Title":"","Type":0,"TypeId":0},{"Id":2,"ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/bands\/2.jpg","BrandId":0,"Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":true,"Disabled":false,"Title":"","Type":0,"TypeId":0},{"Id":3,"ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/bands\/3.jpg","BrandId":0,"Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":true,"Disabled":false,"Title":"","Type":0,"TypeId":0},{"Id":4,"ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/bands\/4.jpg","BrandId":0,"Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":true,"Disabled":false,"Title":"","Type":0,"TypeId":0}],"Brands":[{"Id":4,"ArName":"Fabillo","EnName":"Fabillo","Code":"","Description":"","ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/brands\/fabillo.jpg","Men":true,"Women":false,"Kids":false,"Accessories":false,"FacebookLink":"","InstagrmLink":"","Disabled":false},{"Id":7,"ArName":"Carolina Boix","EnName":"Carolina Boix","Code":"","Description":"","ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/brands\/eva.jpg","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":false,"Accessories":false,"FacebookLink":"","InstagrmLink":"","Disabled":false},{"Id":9,"ArName":"Sport Master","EnName":"Sport Master","Code":"","Description":"","ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/brands\/sportmaster.jpg","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":false,"FacebookLink":"","InstagrmLink":"","Disabled":false},{"Id":10,"ArName":"Bershka","EnName":"Bershka","Code":"","Description":"","ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/brands\/eva.jpg","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":true,"FacebookLink":"","InstagrmLink":"","Disabled":false},{"Id":11,"ArName":"NO EXCESS","EnName":"NO EXCESS","Code":"","Description":"","ImageURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/brands\/noexcess.jpg","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":true,"FacebookLink":"","InstagrmLink":"","Disabled":false}],"Categories":[{"Id":8,"EnName":"T-Shirts","ArName":"بلوزات","Code":"8","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":false,"MenImgURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/Categories\/tshirt01.jpg","WomenImgURL":"","KidsImgURL":"","AccessoriesImgURL":""},{"Id":14,"EnName":"Shoes","ArName":"احذية","Code":"14","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":false,"MenImgURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/Categories\/shoes01.jpg","WomenImgURL":"","KidsImgURL":"","AccessoriesImgURL":""},{"Id":17,"EnName":"Accessories","ArName":"اكسسوارت","Code":"17","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":false,"Accessories":false,"MenImgURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/Categories\/accessories01.jpg","WomenImgURL":"","KidsImgURL":"","AccessoriesImgURL":""},{"Id":6833,"EnName":"Pants","ArName":"بنطلونات","Code":"6833","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":false,"MenImgURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/Categories\/pants01.jpg","WomenImgURL":"","KidsImgURL":"","AccessoriesImgURL":""},{"Id":6834,"EnName":"Shirts","ArName":"قمصان","Code":"6834","Men":true,"Women":true,"Kids":true,"Accessories":false,"MenImgURL":"http:\/\/www.yallaasouq.com\/Categories\/hoodie01.jpg","WomenImgURL":"","KidsImgURL":"","AccessoriesImgURL":""}]}}
```

I know that my json has sub json objects (Bands, Brands, Categories) but in main object (GetTabDataResult) there is (TabId) which is a value not a sub object.

[I also checked the service result in the fiddler and i attached here a photo of the screen...you can check it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ieeaz.png)

Comment: `GetTabDataResult` is a jsonobject not jsonArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
JSONObject jsonOb = jsonObject.getJSONObject("GetTabDataResult");
```

instead of

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetTabDataResult");
```

this is jsonarray

> Bands, Brands, Categories

```
JsonArray bands =jsonOb.getJsonArray("Bands");
```

Hope above code is helpful to you !

Answer (score 1):

I see no JsonArray in the Json String you provided, this is a single json object. Json Arrays are surronded by `[ ]`.

So instead convert it to a normal JSONObject:

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("GetTabDataResult");
```